# How to create an EL-Reference pointing to a Resource in JSF

Tags: jsf

I am currently using something like this in a composite component to create an EL-Reference to a resource:

```
<composite:implementation>

    <ui:param name="resourceName" value="images:#{cc.resourceName}" />

    <h:commandButton id="button" image="#{resource[resourceName]}" />

</composite:implementation>
```

As you can see, `ui:param` refers to a method named `getResourceName()` in the component class. This method determines which resource to load.

I would like to have a solution where the whole `ui:param` thing is unneccessary, something like:

```
<composite:implementation>

    <h:commandButton id="button" image="#{cc.resource}" />

</composite:implementation>
```

Currently I don't even know if this is possible.

Any ideas?

Thx,
DS

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use Resource API provided by JSF then you can just pass the context relative url to the image,

For example:

If this is your custom component:

```
<util:mbt actionMethod="#{bean.show}" resourceName="#{bean.img}" />
```

change it to:

```
<util:mbt actionMethod="#{bean.show}" resource="#{bean.img}" />
```

where bean.getImg() returns a String `"/resources/images/test.jpg"`

Alternatively, use resource API when adding the component like this:

```
<ui:param name="resourceName" value="images:#{bean.img}" />
<util:mbt actionMethod="#{bean.show}" resource="#{resource[resourceName]}" />
```

and use it like this:

```
<composite:implementation>

  .....

  <h:commandButton id="button" action="#{cc.attrs.actionMethod}" image="#{cc.attrs.resource}" />

  .....
</composite:implementation>
```

The question still remains in my mind. "But why?"